# Read small binary file, Out of memory exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, binary

I am reading a small binary file (around 32mb) byte by byte into a data table and converting the first 8 bytes from hex to binary.

With large files I am encountering System Out of memory exception error messages and I cannot think how to improve my code to run more smoothly or faster.

Here is my code:

```
Public Function DecToBin(ByVal DeciValue As Long, Optional ByVal NoOfBits As Integer = 8) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Do While DeciValue > (2 ^ NoOfBits) - 1
        NoOfBits = NoOfBits + 8
    Loop
    DecToBin = vbNullString
    For i = 0 To (NoOfBits - 1)
        DecToBin = CStr((DeciValue And 2 ^ i) / 2 ^ i) & DecToBin
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub importData(ByVal openFile As String)
    If fullFilePath.EndsWith("variable.dat") Then
        Dim importedData As New DataTable
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open(openFile, FileMode.Open))
            Dim pos As Integer = 0
            Dim length As Integer = reader.BaseStream.Length
            loadingBar.loadingLabel.Text = "Lines of data: " & length

            loadingBar.loadingProgress.Minimum = 0
            loadingBar.loadingProgress.Maximum = length
            loadingBar.loadingProgress.Step = 1

            importedData.Columns.Add("Data0")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data1")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data2")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data3")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data4")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data5")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data6")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Data7")

            importedData.Columns.Add("Time")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Date")

            importedData.Columns.Add("Day")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Month")
            importedData.Columns.Add("Year")

            importedData.Columns.Add("Blank")

            While pos < length

                For i = 0 To 15
                    Dim value As Decimal = reader.ReadByte
                    rawDataArray(i) = value.ToString()
                    pos += 1
                Next

                loadingBar.BringToFront()
                loadingBar.Show()
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

                loadingBar.loadingProgress.Value = pos


                convertedDataArray(0) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(0))
                convertedDataArray(1) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(1))
                convertedDataArray(2) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(2))
                convertedDataArray(3) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(3))
                convertedDataArray(4) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(4))
                convertedDataArray(5) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(5))
                convertedDataArray(6) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(6))
                convertedDataArray(7) = DecToBin(rawDataArray(7))

                convertedDataArray(8) = Format((rawDataArray(12) + 0), "00") & ":" & Format((rawDataArray(11) + 0), "00") & ":" & Format((rawDataArray(10) + 0), "00") & "." & Format((rawDataArray(8) * 256) + rawDataArray(9), "000")
                convertedDataArray(9) = Format((rawDataArray(13) + 0), "00") & "." & Format((rawDataArray(14) + 0), "00") & "." & "20" & Format((rawDataArray(15) + 0), "00")

                convertedDataArray(10) = Format((rawDataArray(13) + 0), "00")
                convertedDataArray(11) = Format((rawDataArray(14) + 0), "00")
                convertedDataArray(12) = Format((rawDataArray(15) + 0), "00")

                importedData.Rows.Add(convertedDataArray)
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While
            loadingBar.Close()
            importedData.DefaultView.Sort = "Year,Month,Day,Time"
            dataGrid.DataSource = importedData.DefaultView
        End Using
        dataGrid.Columns(0).Visible = False ' Data 0
        dataGrid.Columns(1).Visible = False ' Data 1
        dataGrid.Columns(2).Visible = False ' Data 2
        dataGrid.Columns(3).Visible = False ' Data 3
        dataGrid.Columns(4).Visible = False ' Data 4
        dataGrid.Columns(5).Visible = False ' Data 5
        dataGrid.Columns(6).Visible = False ' Data 6
        dataGrid.Columns(7).Visible = False ' Data 7
        dataGrid.Columns(8).Visible = True ' Data Time
        dataGrid.Columns(9).Visible = True ' Data Date
        dataGrid.Columns(10).Visible = False ' Data Day
        dataGrid.Columns(11).Visible = False ' Data Month
        dataGrid.Columns(12).Visible = False ' Data Year
        dataGrid.Columns(13).Visible = False ' Data Blank

    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong file selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Example of data being read:

> 3F F3 45 C6 03 00 11 00 00 6F 1F 1D 16 12 07 0D

Example of output:

> 00111111 11110011 01000101 11000110 00000011 00000000 00010001 00000000 22:29:31.111 18.07.2013 18 07 13

Comment: the question belongs on codereview

Comment: @peer I don't see how; it is asking about a specific problem - OOM when processing what is, despite the OP's description, a ***small*** file

Comment: Why are you doing all the `ToString()` / `DecToBin` stuff? `ReadByte()` already ***returns a `byte`*** (specifically, it returns an `int` which is either negative for EOF, or in the range 0-255 - it just needs to be cast as a `byte` and: job done): do you have some example input/output of what it is you are trying to do? because it looks a lot like you're inventing work in the middle here... Also: what is the type of `convertedDataArray` ? (it isn't shown)

Comment: I did the DecToBin thing to convert the HEX value to a binary byte in the form of 01101001 etc and the ToString() stuff is to get the seperate parts of the file and join them together to create time and date from the file.

Comment: Edited first post to show input and output example

Answer (score 1):

Getting `System.OutOfMemoryException` means there's no single *consecutive* region of unallocated memory of the required size available. It doesn't necessarily mean you have no memory left but rather that the memory is fragmented way too much.

One way to solve the problem might be by using [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) class which (as the name implies) will map part of the process's virtual memory to the data on your hard drive, for example.

Another way you could try dealing with the problem can be calling `GC.Collect` which will compact the memory as part of the garbage collection process. Although, I'd strongly discourage from using this method.

You can use [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or windbg (ships as part of the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)) to see where your memory is being used.

As for your code, you don't seem to have anything suspicious in it (apart from `DecToBin` which Marc Gravell has already pointed to).

Hope this helps.